# Android: Is there a way to stop AlarmReceiver fired in BootReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am using a Boot receiver to fire AlarmManager,so that it repeats it's task every minute. I'd like the user to have in app option to enable/disable action that is done in every repeat of AlarmManager. So far I only used only a lame solution. I set user's preference in SharedPreferences and in every repeat of AlarmManager I check for user's preference in SharedPreferences and based on this preference the functionality is either executed or ignored.

So far to my best knowledge, there is no way to completely destroy AlarmManager from within itself. but I might be wrong.

Also, since boot receiver is registered in AndroidManifest.xml and a BroadcastReceiver only really exists when onReceive is called, there is probably no way of getting a reference to AlarmManager object, so that I could cancel the alarm from the outside with AlarmManager.cancel. But I might be wrong about all this.

So I'd like to ask, if I am mistaken about all this, or if there is some way to completely destroy/cancel AlarmManager started on Boot(from inside the AlaramManager, or outside, doesn't matter). Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can cancel the alarm any time by using the same Pending Intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(show.this, TimeAlarm.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(show.this, 0,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        <Alarm_Manager_Object>.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. Yes, I know about method AlarmManager.cancel, the problem is however, I don't have the reference to Alarm_Manager_Object. The reference to this object exists only in onReceive method of BootReceiver class(which extends BroadcastReceiver and fires at system boot) and this method keeps the reference for maybe 10 seconds or so and then the reference is lost, not accessible - or so I believe, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Just fetch a new one in that case and call AlarmManager#cancel(PendingIntent) on that one. The important part is the PendingIntent.

Comment: Oh, sorry, you are completely right, I just realized how stupid I was. Thank you very much guys.