# How to do things in the background in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

My app has an activity, an admin receiver and an alarm manager receiver. I want to be able to do the following things even when the app is closed:

1- disable the alarm and make a boolean preference false when device administrator is disabled
2- do some administrative tasks after the alarm is received.

I tried putting the code in the receivers but then the code only worked when the app is working. Then I tried initializing all the code related to the alarm manager and the device administrator before onCreate() but I couldn't reference the code in the receiver because some of it was dynamic.

So how can I achieve this?

The code

```
public class mainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

static EditText numberOfHours;
static TextView hourText;
static Button setButton;
static Context context;

static DevicePolicyManager dpm;
static ComponentName admin;
static boolean adminCheck;
static Intent intent;

static SharedPreferences preferences;
static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
static boolean appSet;

static AlarmManager alarmManager;
static PendingIntent alarmIntent;
static Intent mIntent;
static Calendar calendar;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    hourText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hourText);
    numberOfHours = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberOfHours);
    setButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setButton);
    context = this;

    dpm = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
    admin = new ComponentName(context, adminReceiver.class);
    intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
    intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, admin);
    intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION, "The app needs to be a device administrator to be able to lock the screen");

    preferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("appSet", false);
    appSet = preferences.getBoolean("appSet", false);

    alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    mIntent = new Intent(context, alarmReceiver.class);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 24, mIntent, 0);
    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 24);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    setButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (adminCheck) {
                        numberOfHours.setEnabled(false);
                        setButton.setEnabled(false);
                        setButton.setText("Done");
                        editor.putBoolean("appSet", true).commit();

                        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, alarmIntent);
                    }
                    else {

                        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

                    }
            }
        });
    }

static public class adminReceiver extends DeviceAdminReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onEnabled(context, intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onDisabled(context, intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPasswordChanged(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onPasswordChanged(context, intent);
    }
}

static public class alarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your code to run when your app is closed, you might want to look into [Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

Comment: I want it to run when one of the receivers gets my intents. And yes maybe this can be done with a service or an intentService but I don't know how.

Comment: I put it in the question.

Comment: did you specify the receiver in the manifest?  And are you getting any Logcat errors, or is it just "not working"?

Comment: The two receivers are working but when I add something like `alarmMananger.cancel(alarmIntent)` to onDisabled in adminReceiver it only works when the activity is working (onCreate is called). After closing the app and disabling device manager from the settings I think alarmIntent is null and that causes the app to crash.

Comment: What if you move the alarm intent instantiation from `onCreate` to `onReceive`?

Comment: you mean initialize alarmIntent in onReceive? I tried putting it a long with the other variables but that didn't work. I tried putting it in onDisabled but that didn't work either.

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268657/android-is-there-a-way-to-stop-alarmreceiver-fired-in-bootreceiver

Comment: I tried to do this today and it works!. I just had to initialize the needed variables in _onDisabled_ because that's where I wanted to disable the alarm. I also added the other things that I wanted to do in my receivers. I had to use `context.getSharedPreferences` instead of `getPreferences` because `getPreferences` can only be used in the activity that had it and it's not static. I was also able to use `getSystemService` in the receiver by adding `context.` before it. Thanks for the help :)